# Set nested variables for swagger.yml play app using iheartradio/play-swagger

Tags: scala, play-json

I'm using iheartradio/play-swagger lib to generate swagger.json to server UI. I'm not able to set nested variable(title under info) inside swagger.yml. Though I can set, for example host variable.

swagger.yml

```
  swagger: "2.0"
    info:
      description: "API"
      version: "1.0.0"
      title: "Brand API"
    host: "api.radio"
    tags:
    - name: "brand"
```

Here is swagger controller code

```
val authUrl = "brand"
lazy val swagger = Action { request =>
        generator.generate().map(_ + ("title" -> JsString(authUrl))).fold(
          e => InternalServerError("Couldn't generate swagger."),
          s => Ok(s))
      }
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is not working?

Comment: I'm trying to set title variable under info(in swagger.yml) thru code. I want authUrl value to be assigned to title in swagger.yml. In map, how to specify the nested variable.    generator.generate().map(_ + ("info"."title" -> JsString(authUrl))) isn;t working

Comment: You may want to have a look to `deepMerge` method on `JsObject` to easily add a field in a deeper level than the root. However you are talking about JSON and Yaml so I'm confused. What's the return type of `generatoe.generate()` ?

Comment: https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger/blob/master/docs/AlternativeSetup.md. iheartradio play-swagger is used to generate a swagger spec json.  generate() returns JsObject

Comment: For more details http://iheartradio.github.io/play-swagger/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to add a property in a nested piece of JSON is to use `JsObject#deepMerge`.

In your example, replace

```scala
generator.generate().map(_ + ("title" -> JsString(authUrl)))
```

With:

```scala
val toMerge = Json.parse(s"""{ "info": { "title": "$authUrl" } }""") // or build it manually
generator.generate().map(_.deepMerge(toMerge))
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks for the help !!